# Print Hindi (regional languages) text from a unicode list

Tags: python, parsing, hindi

I have unicode array for each single character of Hindi language but now want to display and store it in such way that any text editor and python's output terminal etc are able to print it properly.
Since in Hindi and many other languages also two or three unicode characters form a single alphabet in that language(Hindi in my case).How do i display them together, same thing must be happening when we copy those text from one editor/html/pdf etc to some other editor, how can i do this in my python app ?

Comment: As an example this html book written in regional language 'https://storyweaver.org.in/stories/33260-pari-aani-aai',
when i copy text from this to any editor it copies fine like this 'लाडाने घरी तिला'
i want to display like this 
currently it displays like 'िा कथा स  ि आप'
here few instances where single alphabet is split into two

Comment: What do you mean by "python's output terminal"? As far as text editors go, that's not under your control (unless you have its source code).

Comment: @martineau , i forgot to mention that I am using PyCharm as my IDE for development so its output terminal 
so is there some interface/specifications provided by PyCharm's output terminal (and in general any editor) in which to store such data so that can be rendered appropriately. I am hoping for something like this as many languages have similar issues and people build web apps /servers using Django which is essential Python based in those languages